# How can i run docker-compose.yml without using Git?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I've built 2 nice little Docker containers that run on my local machine with **docker-compose.yml**

`docker-compose -f "C:\Users\Sebastian\source\repos\Bananas\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\Sebastian\source\repos\Bananas\docker-compose.override.yml" --no-ansi up -d`

My project looks like this:

[image]

My docker image is pushed to a Docker registry.

If I want to run my docker-compose.yml command above on someone elses machine I could check this project into GIT and have them pull it and run the **docker-compose.yml** command listed above.

**My question is:** Is there a way that they can run my command, or something to the same effect without having to go through GIT?

Like can they do a docker pull  and somehow run it that way?

Comment: The caller needs to get the `docker-compose.yml` file somehow, but the system isn't intrinsically tied to git (or any other source control system).  `scp` and email would work fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the objective of the [docker-app](https://github.com/docker/app) project. At present, it's still experimental, so the behavior can change, and there's a lot of active development behind it right now. After installing docker-app, the workflow looks like:

```
docker-app init -c docker-compose.yml -s $app_name
docker-app push --namespace $hub_user_name --tag $tag_version
```

The push command packages and sends the app up to docker hub.

Deploying on another machine with Swarm Mode or Kubernetes is with a deploy command like:

```
docker-app deploy $hub_user_name/$app_name:$tag_version
```

Or you can use the render command to output the compose yml file that you can use with docker-compose:

```
docker-app render $hub_user_name/$app_name:$tag_version | docker-compose -f - up
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! Funny that - I used to go to school with/sit in the same classes as Matt Smith :P